# Where are pptp logs in openSUSE 42.2?

Tags: networking, logs, opensuse, vpn, pptp

I trying to set up `pptp` vpn connection in `openSUSE Leap 42.2`, but I got an error `VPN connection failed`..
I can't see nothing in `dmesg` and I have no `/var/log/messages` file

I've installed `rsyslog` but there are still no messages about `pptp` connection error in `/var/log/messages` file

Where can I see `pptp` logs?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, journalctl manages all logs and messages of units (services from SystemCtl). You can see logs and messages from NetworkManager by the following command:

```
journalctl -u NetworkManager
```